# uploading multiple files with ng-file-upload

Tags: c#, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and I just can't seem to get it to work.

My html is

```
<input ngf-select ng-model="files" ngf-multiple="true" id="files" name="files" type="file" value="Choose File(s)" />
```

and a button once the files have been added

```
<button ng-click="uploadFiles(files)">Upload</button>
```

My controller is similar to the examples provided on [github](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#usage) and jsfiddle.

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {
    if (files && files.length) {
    angular.forEach(files, function (file) {
        $log.warn("counter");
        if (files && !file.$error) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: "FileUpload.ashx",
                file: file,
                fields: {
                    FormInstanceGuid: $scope.model.FormInstanceGuid,
                    FormName: $scope.model.Template.Name
                }
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $log.info("We have succeeded in our call!");
                $log.info(response);
            }, function (reason) {
                $log.info("We have failed in our call!");
                $log.info(reason);
            });
        }
    });
```

My problem comes down to the fact that the UploadHandler (on the server) is only called once and there is only ever 1 file coming in. My thinking is that it should be called once for each file as it's inside a forEach loop.

```
if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0) //This is never greater than 1
{
    HttpFileCollection SelectedFiles = context.Request.Files;
    for (int i = 0; i < SelectedFiles.Count; i++) {
        HttpPostedFile file = SelectedFiles[i];                        
    }
}
```

I've checked the network tab, and each file is in its own POST.

Comment: so you are saying.. u r receive one post per file uploaded? so 3 post for 3 selected files?

Comment: You are sending the files one by one so you should expect 1 file per request on the server too.

Comment: @danial you are right (durr moment), but the uploadHandler method is only called once. No matter how many files I attach, it is only called once and that's it.

Comment: Do you see multiple post requests being sent to the server in your browser's network tab?